# HTaccess doesnt foward to https

Tags: .htaccess, https

In my htaccess file i have a rewritecond that should foward all http request to https, but for some reason i doesnt work, and this isnt my area of expertise, can you help me out?

i am currently using this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs()
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|css|flv|js|swf|php|ico|webm|mp4)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747758-Force-your-site-to-load-securely-with-an-htaccess-file

Answer (score 0):

The two rewrite conditions are connected via a logical `AND` operator per default. That means that the redirection rule is *not* applied if one condition is `false`, so for example if the host name *does* start with "www."...

Use a logical `OR` operator instead:

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs()
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R]
```